# What types of testing is right for server OS upgrade

Tags: manual-testing

My company is doing server OS upgrade, so as a tester I would want to know what types of testing is most helpful in this process?

Comment: server OS upgrade tests.
Seriously- you need to come with more context and ideas you thought about, at the moment the way your question is written we can fill books with answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run through below check list and pick applicable ones for your environment

- Regression Testing - Ensure Server, Features stable and running fine post upgrade
- For browser upgrades - Compatibility testing
- For specific machine upgrades (Not all machines upgraded) - If not all systems are upgraded then basic testing needs to ensure different versions of platforms do not have any impact. Connectivity of upstream and downstream system post upgrade is successful
- Monitor resource usage (CPU / DB) and measure if there is any abnormal spike. There could be override / change in default system param. This may hurt performance aspects
- In case of upgrade failure test the roll back strategy
- All this upgrade need to be done from QA-UAT finally to prod
- Managing downtime during the upgrade (Read only access / fail over systems ?)

Answer (score 0):

Expecting you have a [DTAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development,_testing,_acceptance_and_production) setup: Upgrade the Acceptance server OS and let any users depended on the services of the server accept that their applications are still working.

For operational testing have a look at what [ITIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Technology_Infrastructure_Library) describes: http://wiki.en.it-processmaps.com/index.php/Service_Validation_and_Testing